# wordpress is generating too many Image Sizes

Tags: images

I have removed the default image sizes, and added my custom image sizes with this code:

```
// Remove default image sizes
function remove_default_image_sizes( $sizes ) {
  
    /* Default WordPress */
    unset( $sizes[ 'thumbnail' ]);       // Remove Thumbnail (150 x 150 hard cropped)
    unset( $sizes[ 'medium' ]);          // Remove Medium resolution (300 x 300 max height 300px)
    unset( $sizes[ 'medium_large' ]);    // Remove Medium Large (added in WP 4.4) resolution (768 x 0 infinite height)
    unset( $sizes[ 'large' ]);           // Remove Large resolution (1024 x 1024 max height 1024px)

    /* With WooCommerce */
    unset( $sizes[ 'shop_thumbnail' ]);  // Remove Shop thumbnail (180 x 180 hard cropped)
    unset( $sizes[ 'shop_catalog' ]);    // Remove Shop catalog (300 x 300 hard cropped)
    unset( $sizes[ 'shop_single' ]);     // Shop single (600 x 600 hard cropped)

    return $sizes;
    }
  
    add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'remove_default_image_sizes' );
//


// post thumbnail sizes
    

    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'vkb_setup_theme' );
    function vkb_setup_theme() {

        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

        set_post_thumbnail_size( 250, 250, true );

        add_image_size( 'XS', 128 );
        add_image_size( 'S', 256 );
        add_image_size( 'M', 512 );
        add_image_size( 'XL', 1024 );
    }
//
```

There should be XS, S, M, XL, Post_thumbnail, and the original size, that`s 6.

However when I uploaded a big image(2898 x 2346) for testing, I have 9 images, I have additional this 3 sizes: -1536x1253, -2048x1671, and one named -scaled with the size of 2560x2088.

Why do I have this additional sizes, and how can I get rid of them?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I fonud the answer here:
https://gist.github.com/iftee/73cbd9f080c5c7a943cff5e806997f90?permalink_comment_id=3314876#gistcomment-3314876

I added:

```
unset( $sizes['1536x1536'] );
unset( $sizes['2048x2048'] );

remove_image_size( '1536x1536' );
remove_image_size( '2048x2048' );
```

This removes the two big image sizes, but the -scaled image size is still there

I found out this:

*`When a new image is uploaded, WordPress will detect if it is a “big” image by checking if its height or its width is above a big_image threshold. The default threshold value is 2560px, filterable with the new big_image_size_threshold filter. If an image height or width is above this threshold, it will be scaled down, with the threshold being used as max-height and max-width value. The scaled-down image will be used as the largest available size. In this case, the original image file is stored in the uploads directory and its name is stored in another array key in the image meta array: original_image. To be able to always get the path to an originally uploaded image a new function wp_get_original_image_path() was introduced.`*

source:
https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/10/09/introducing-handling-of-big-images-in-wordpress-5-3/

To remove it:

```
add_filter( 'big_image_size_threshold', '__return_false' );
```